# Data backup needed before Apple Store screen repair?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, backup, repair

My 2016 Macbook Pro screen has vertical stripes of bad pixels and I just scheduled to take it in for repair. Do they usually just fix the screen or do they replace the entire computer? I'm curious because I really want to know the following -

Although it's advised, do I actually need to back up my data before taking the computer in for a monitor issue?

Answer (score 4):

**You need to backup your data.**
**Period.**

There is a new adage for the digital world we live in...

> "Any data which is not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary"

This translates to one on-site backup, e.g. Time Machine -  & one off-site backup, iCloud, BackBlaze, CrashPlan etc.

The first is to cover for if you break your machine irreparably.
The second is for if the house burns down too.

Without **both** your data can be lost at the *'whim of the gods'*... forever.

Please have a read of my somewhat tongue-in-cheek question I posted on the Ask Different Meta a while ago

**[Restore from backup?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/restore-from-backup)**

Answer (score 2):

### The usual procedure at a Genius Bar

Apple will usually replace the display ("Display Assembly") only. You will see the items that will be replaced before a Genius in an Apple Store will let you sign to accept the repair.

### Why you still should backup your data

Yes, in case something goes wrong during the repair **you should still have a backup of your data**. In case the logic board gets damaged they will replace the display and the logic board. All other components will remain the same.